# Same query, different execution plans on Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

We have a query that appends the results to other table. We got different execution plans randomly. We use the execution plan to get the number of records than has been append, but this makes the feature unusable for us. It seems that this changed few weeks ago.

[image: The good one]

[image: The one with an odd execution plan]

Job ids:

This jobs ids are different from the images, but they have the same problem

bquijob_6e6a8772_1610d595b56

bquijob_5e9c0051_1610d58c352

Comment: please post the two job id so BQ engineering team can verify it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue corresponds to a known bug. The fix is being rolled out, most likely next week, but the exact date may change.

Erik, Technical Solutions Engineer, Google cloud support.